# How to print local disk of solaris server with some custom text

Tags: shell

I am writing a shell script to get the list of local disk with some custom text.
I achieve to print the output but its not coming in required format. Please help to correct the code

Code:

```
#! /usr/bin/env ksh
name=`uname -n`
df -kl | while read line;
do
(echo $name.disk_usage && echo $line | awk '{print $6 $5}') | tr '\n' " "
done
```

Output is coming in one line
    Solaris.disk_usage Mountedcapacity Solaris.disk_usage /7% Solaris.disk_usage /devices0% Solaris.disk_usage /system/contract0% Solaris.disk_usage /proc0%

Expected output is

```
Solaris.disk_usage.root 7% 
Solaris.disk_usage.root.devices 0% 
Solaris.disk_usage.root.system_contract 0%
Solaris.disk_usage.root.proc 0%
```

means other than number all text should be concatenated as well as second '/' should be replace by '_' symbol

Comment: well, you are removing all newlines with `tr '\n' " "` so it's expected.

Comment: When i don't use --- tr '\n' " "   --- then it print both echo output in two different line

Solaris.disk_usage
Mountedcapacity
Solaris.disk_usage
/7%
Solaris.disk_usage
/devices0%
Solaris.disk_usage
/system/contract0%
Solaris.disk_usage
/proc0%